# How to start a Java process with high priority on windows system

Tags: java, windows, multithreading

First of all this question is not about thread priority.

I have created a Java program let's say Test.java. when I do

C:/> java Test , I mean when I run my program, windows operating system starts a Java process with a normal priority that we can see in windows task manager.

My program needs huge system resources. If java process has normal priority it may not get system resources as much as it need. I can set this process priority to high from windows task manager by going to a process right click it and set priority as high.

I want to set this process priority to high either programmatically from my java program or while running the program from command prompt.

Comment: From [here](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-run-application-higher-priority) To start an application at a priority other than the default use the start command, e.g.

start /<priority> <application>, e.g. start /high winword

Comment: I have checked this. In this it's mentioned a command to run a process with high priority, but it's not working. CMD /C start /high winword. But when I check its priority in windows task manager its priority is normal.

Comment: It works for me - see below. Probably, you are having issues with privileges or some specific Windows version. Updating your answer with these details should help. For example, from the source I've provided above _"To use the /realtime option you have to be logged on as a user with Administrator privileges."_. I assume you have to have appropriate privileges even to run it as high priority.

Comment: Try execute cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me this way: from cmd `start /high <app>`

[image]

Windows version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. If I use the above command for a program like paint, winword it's working fine. But when I created a batch file to run a Java program, and then I am trying to run batch file using the above command, it's starting cmd process with high priority but in windows task manager java process still started with low priority

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. Once I execute the below command, C:\>start /high java -jar MyJar.jar a Java process has started with high priority. Thanks a lot